# Long Range USB bluetooth for PC - Read data with C#

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth-lowenergy, usb

I am working on desktop app where I need to read the scan data from USB bluetooth dongle. The signals are broadcasting and long range USB bluetooth can receive it.
As per my understading as this USB device so I can read the data with USB scan.
I am using this Long rang Bluetooth Dongle=>https://www.amazon.com/dp/B09KG7QQ5V?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details

In the below code how can I find the venorId,productId.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Devices.Usb;

class USBBluetoothReader
{
    private UsbDevice usbDevice;

    public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        // Define the USB device selector based on the vendor ID and product ID.
        var deviceSelector = UsbDevice.GetDeviceSelector(vendorId, productId);

        // Get a list of USB devices that match the selector.
        var devices = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(deviceSelector);

        // Check if a device was found.
        if (devices.Count > 0)
        {
            // Open the USB device.
            usbDevice = await UsbDevice.FromIdAsync(devices[0].Id);

            if (usbDevice != null)
            {
                // You can now communicate with the USB Bluetooth reader.
                // Depending on the device and its protocol, you may need to use Input and Output pipes for data transfer.
                // Refer to the device's documentation for communication details.

                // For example, to read data from an Input pipe:
                var inputPipe = usbDevice.DefaultInterface.DefaultBulkInPipe;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[inputPipe.EndpointDescriptor.MaxPacketSize];
                var bytesRead = await inputPipe.ReadAsync(buffer.AsBuffer());

                // Process the data in the buffer.
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle device opening failure.
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle device not found.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you try to access the device at USB level? Windows will claim the device and make it available through Bluetooth APIs. It will no longer allow direct USB access.

Comment: @Codo - Agreed with you. The requirement is that the signal are public broadcast and need to receive it through Bluetooth. I have USB long range bluetooth receiver. I am stuck at how to read the data received by long range bluetooth. Hence, I have tried to read it using USB.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided more information about the sender and the protocol it uses. Is it Bluetooth Public Broadcast Profile?

Comment: @Codo - Yes it is public broadcast. I'm flying a drone which broadcast the signals and using Bluetooth dongle receiver. I want to read the received data using c#.

Comment: "public broadcast" is not necessarily *Bluetooth Public Broadcast Profile*. And since it's a drone, it most likely isn't. You need to provide dependable technical information about the sender. Otherwise it's very difficult to help you.

Comment: @Codo I'm following the https://www.opendroneid.org/ and https://github.com/opendroneid for this. I'm working on desktop app to receive the drone data through LE Bluetooth receiver.

Comment: Your starting point should probably be [BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.advertisement.bluetoothleadvertisementwatcher?view=winrt-22621). The OpenDroneID Android app listens for Bluetooth LE advertisement with service UUID 0000fffa-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb and service data [ 0x0D ] (byte array with a single byte).